# How to create sub domains for a live server on xampp?

Tags: xampp

I know that this is a duplicate, but all the other answers I read didn't work for me.

I want to create sub domains for my Apache web server, I want to either be able to access it by one of the following. I just found out that the only people who can access the website are users on my network, do you know why?

- sub.domain.com
- sub.localhost
- sub.000.00.00.00 (Hidden for security)
- sub.127.0.0.1

I tried editing the vhost.config file and manage to break Xampp. I am reinstalling it as I type this.

Also is it possible to host multiple websites on a single server? Please explain to me all of this, I been playing around with Xampp and Goggling for too long now.

The error I am getting is the server isn't responding to sub.localhost, but it is for localhost.

httpd-vhost.config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/site1"
ServerName localhost

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/site2"
ServerName sub.localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

[errors.log](http://prntscr.com/7pdkvq)

Comment: `sub.domain.com` and `sub.localhost` are valid host names, you can setup your local server to serve requests to these. The other two are incalid hostnames, that is not possible.

Comment: In general: reinstalling neither solves issues nor is it required. Just backup your configuration files before you make changes, so that you can always return to the previous state.

Comment: If you want us to help, then you have to post your configuration attempts here. Along with the messages you see in the http servers log files, especially the error log file. _That_ is where the server tells you what the problem is.

Comment: What you want to do is this: add a separate vhost definition for each of those hostnames. Each requires a DocumentRoot. All you need for that is explained in the documentation, which also brings good examples: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/examples.html

Comment: Okay I updated my answer, backup the file I edited. And posted the error logs details. I also added a separate vhost for both of the domains. For some reason I can access localhost, but not sub.localhost.

Comment: By "the server isn't responding to sub.localhost" you mean that the server does not record any request I assume? Then you have not added the same resolution for that hostname to your local name resolution configuration. Easiest is to add the hostname to the file `/etc/hosts` (or it's equivalent on MS-Windows, no idea what that might be).

Comment: I did change my host file (C:/Windows/System32/Drivers/ect/hosts) to allow the two domains, Still is not working.